# sbt native packager: How to add a logrotate conf file to /etc/logrotate.d/myconf

Tags: sbt-native-packager

I have :
      mappings in Universal ++= Seq(
        file("my-application/src/universal/etc/logrotate.d/my-application") -> "/etc/logrotate.d/my-application"
)

But this puts it into /usr/share/my-application/etc/logroteate.d/my-application

Answer (score 0):

Putting mappings in **Universal** will put them inside the installation directory. 
You have to use the linuxPackageMappings.

Start by reading [the docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/DetailedTopics/linux.html) on this. Then take a look at some of [the tests](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/sbt-test/debian/test-mapping-helpers/build.sbt), which also act as examples.

Unfortunatly the packaging API is not refactored yet thus a bit spread out.
The [LinuxPlugin trait](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/linux/LinuxPlugin.scala) contains some parts of the mappings methods, too.

```
linuxPackageMappings += packageMapping(files: (File, String)*)
```